# External IdP using SAML + mobile app. How to configure to call connected app callback URL?

Tags: mobile, saml

I'm using an external IdP/federated Id and trying to log into my mobile app (using the Salesforce SDK). However, instead I'm taken to the Salesforce dashboard within the login WebView and never actually logged into the app. I notice that the connected app callback url is never called. Where/how do I configure that? Is that something that I can change within SF, or do I need to change something on the IdP side? I see that the IdP is POSTing a SAMLResponse to the Salesforce Login URL. Should it instead be POSTing the same to the OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint?

Comment: What error are you getting ? You would see an error from SFDC for SAML request

Comment: No error. I'm using My Domain's name as the login host within the SDK, which takes me to my external IdP's access portal within a WebView. Upon successful authentication, I'm redirected to the main Salesforce dashboard (https://<my domain>.my.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp) within the same WebView. I need instead for the WebView to be dismissed and to be logged into the app itself. From what I understand, that occurs when the WebView is redirected to the connected app callback url with access_token, instance_url, etc. The question is what do I need to do to accomplish that?

Comment: I can see that authenticating with the IdP does an HTTP POST to the Salesforce Login URL with the SAML response, which in turn logs me into the dashboard. Does the OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint play a role in the solution? Are there changes needed on the IdP side or within Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [Relay State Parameter](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176508&language=en_US) to add redirection ability .

RelayState will be sent as an HTTP Parameter along side a SAML AuthnRequest ( per the SAML standard ).

To set it up in salesforce,  add "&RelayState=FOO" to your login URL. For example, if the IDP init URL is

https://identity.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0spE00000008XXX

You'd end up with

https://identity.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0spE00000008XXX&RelayState=FOO

Comment: I'm not sure that I need a simple redirect. When the user authenticates against the IdP's Login URL, the SAMLResponse is POSTed to Salesforce Login URL listed in my SSO settings. However, that doesn't generate the OAuth credentials that the app needs to login (those are retrieved by POSTing the SAML response from the IdP to the OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint). For that to happen, does the IdP need to perform that POST, or is there a setting within SF that can facilitate?

Comment: Also, I would still need to use that same IdP to login to the SF dashboard from the web.

Comment: @IsaacCharny I think you may be looking for this OAuth flow with SAML https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5